# Is there a way to remove/delete/hide the activity from "activities I am following" section?

Tags: user-profile, administration, central-administration, user-profile-property

Is there a way to remove/delete/hide the activity from "activities I am following" section? I do not want to hide the entire section itself like mentioned in this URL - `http://donalconlon.wordpress.com/category/sharepoint/`

Just want to remove/delete/hide an activity "New Blog Post" from the "activities I am following" section

Answer (score 2):

If you edit your profile, there are a bunch of checkboxes toward the bottom of the items you are following. Those are the only options you have to configure.

Comment: John, As a SharePoint admin, I want to remove/hide the unwanted activities so that it will not be available to the end-users on his editprofile page.

Comment: It's pretty much all or nothing. You can configure the social options on the user profile service application in central admin.

Comment: I could not find a link to "social options" on the user profile service application, could you please tell me where I can find.

Comment: Here you go: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee721063.aspx

Answer (score 0):

I agree with John that you can't change the options that appear in the "Activites I'm following" section.

Howver, if you want to hide this section completely from the edit profile page then you need to do some work in Central Admin in the **User Profile Application** settings

1. In the "***People***" section, click on "***Manage User Properties***"
2. You will need to create a new Sub-Type (as you will be moving the section to this sub-type).  Click "***Manage Sub types***" and enter a new Name for the sub-type and click Create.
3. Back in the "***Manage User Properties*** screen", scroll down to the "***Newsfeed Settings***" section and click on the "Newsfeed Settings" text and select the "Edit" option from the drop down.
4. Uncheck the "***Default User Profile Subtype***" box and any other subtypes you have so that you only have the one you created above as the solo selected item.
5. Click OK and the check (in the edit profile page) that the section no longer displays.
6. If you need it back, or need it for certain subtypes then re-check the box as above.